# establishing socket connection between different machines on same network

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ip

I have written a basic client and server programs for socket communication in linux 
server code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void error(char * msg){     perror(msg);    exit(1); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd,listenfd,portno,clilen,n;    char buffer[256];   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
            if (argc<2)         error("error port number not provided");

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   if(sockfd<0)        error("error while creating socket ");      bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));   portno = atoi(argv[1]);     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;     serv_addr.sin_port
= htons(portno);

    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof serv_addr)<0)        error("error while binding socket");    listen(sockfd,5);   clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

            if ((listenfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr,&clilen))<0)             error("error while initializing listening");    printf("listening for connections.."); while(strncmp(buffer,"bye",3)!=0){       bzero(buffer,256); //n= read(listenfd,buffer,255);      n= recv(listenfd,buffer,255,0);         if(n<0)             error("no message");        printf("\nfrd:%s",buffer);      printf("\nyou:");       fgets(buffer,255,stdin); //n= write(listenfd,buffer,sizeof buffer);         n=send(listenfd,(char*)&buffer,strlen(buffer),0);       if(n<0)             printf("message not sent");

    } close(sockfd); }
```

Client Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

void error(char * msg){     perror(msg);    exit(1); }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd,portno,n;    char buffer[256];   struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;   struct hostent *server;
            if (argc<3)         error("error port number not provided");

    portno = atoi(argv[2]);         sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);   if(sockfd<0)        error("error while creating socket ");      server
=(struct hostent *)gethostbyname(argv[1]);  if(server == NULL){         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");        exit(0);    }


    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));  serv_addr.sin_family
= AF_INET; //bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(portno);


        if(connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)        error("error while connecting..");  while(strncpy(buffer,"bye",3)!=0){      bzero(buffer,256);      printf("\nYou:");       fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                //n= write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));   n=send(sockfd,(char*)&buffer,strlen(buffer),0);         if(n<0)             printf("message not delivered\n");      bzero(buffer,256);      //n= read(sockfd,buffer,255);       n= recv(sockfd,buffer,255,0);       printf("\nfrd:%s",buffer);  }

close(sockfd); }
```

when I run these programs on my system in different terminals, it runs perfectly fine and I am able to send and recienve messages

server terminal

> h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~/C$ ./hserver 5400 listening for connections..
>   frd:hi
>
> you:hello
>
> frd:i think its working
>
> you:yes it is
>
> client terminal
>
> h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~/C$ ./hclient localhost 5400
>
> You:hi
>
> frd:hello
>
> You:i think its working
>
> frd:yes it is
>
> You:

but when I try to run client code and server code in different machines connected to internet, after starting server, when I start the client code on different machine with ip of machine running server code as argument, I am unable to extablish connection, error- connection refused.

is being behind the router causing ip problems..or there is something I am missing..?
kindly advise how to run client and server on different machines.

output of iptables -L command

```
`root@h2o-Vostro-1015:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`
```

output of ifconfig, wireless lan connection is shown as eth1

```
h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:b9:01:33:9c  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:312 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1620 (1.6 KB)  TX bytes:27565 (27.5 KB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:60:76:4d:ed:31  
          inet addr:172.16.52.71  Bcast:172.16.55.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e60:76ff:fe4d:ed31/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:172420 errors:2 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:2451108
          TX packets:62286 errors:31 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:62717146 (62.7 MB)  TX bytes:7900633 (7.9 MB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xc000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:6619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6619 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:912141 (912.1 KB)  TX bytes:912141 (912.1 KB)
```

output of iwconfig

```
h2o@h2o-Vostro-1015:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Link Quality:5  Signal level:211  Noise level:199
          Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0
```

Comment: Well, did you setup port forwarding on your router? Assuming the two machines are not on the same LAN.

Comment: Is it possible that you have IP tables running on the server, and it's blocking incoming connections?  Try running `iptables -L` on the server to see.

Comment: @TimČas, thanks Tim for your suggestion,actually both the machines are running on the same LAN and have same external ip...

Comment: @mti2935, thanks, I ran this command on both server and client machines and got following result
-edited in question

Comment: OK, it doesn't look like iptables is blocking anything on the server.  If you run the server program, then try to connect to the server from your client using telnet (instead of you client program), does it connect?

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a networking problem that is preventing you from connecting.  Are you sure both hosts are on the same subnet?  Can you ping from one host to the other on the local network?

Comment: I checked that, and i am able to get response to ping from either of the machine to the other one

Comment: Did you try @mti2935's suggestion. Run the server program on one machine, can you telnet to it from the other?

Comment: I think I am facing something rather odd, at times I am able to ping the machines from one another and other times it just hangs there waiting for something on terminal (no response to ping) and sometimes  destination unreachable.
in addition to that when I closely looked at the ifconfig output the connection which is wireless connection is showing as eth1 instead of wlan. output of ifconfig edited in question